# Queried column disappears from results

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, sobject

I just added a new field to a custom Salesforce Object.
I now want to query that field from the database.
If I query it from the developer console, everything is fine.
However...
If I query it from Apex no results are found:

```
[SELECT Id, MyNewString__c FROM FitTips__c]
```

returns an array of Ids

Here's what the log looks like (I set everything to finest)

> 12:36:41.0 (122674445)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:4
>   12:36:41.0 (122898600)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[53]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, MyNewString__c FROM FitTips__c
>   12:36:41.0 (122983672)|LIMIT_USAGE|[53]|SOQL|3|100
>   12:36:41.0 (123006941)|LIMIT_USAGE|[53]|AGGS|1|300
>   12:36:41.0 (133779067)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[53]|Rows:696
>   12:36:41.0 (133803337)|LIMIT_USAGE|[53]|SOQL_ROWS|1392|50000
>   12:36:41.0 (133842485)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:2788
>   12:36:41.0 (134466866)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:20273
>   12:36:41.0 (134510654)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:2788

I've never added a custom field before, did I miss something?

Comment: I don't see a problem here?

Comment: [SELECT Id, MyNewString__c FROM FitTips__c]

returns an array of Ids @sfdcfox

Comment: also, if I query 
[SELECT Id, MyNewString__c,a,b,c,d,e FROM FitTips__c]
I get an array of [id,a,b,c,d,e]

Comment: Do you have the profile permission to view the field?

Comment: @AayushK Good question, I looked at other fields and I can't find anything that makes the permissions differ. Looked all over the object manager and my permissionset list.

Comment: We did not see what you're getting. But if the value for your fields is empty for all rows, you won't see the values in your list.

Comment: @SebastianKessel There are values in some rows. Would them all being blank mean the column doesn't appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no idea what went wrong, but this time I created the new field from the object manager and everything is fine.